# ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE Shows Empty Recent List

Tags: android, android-sdcard, storage-access-framework

I want to provide my application with Write Permission for SD Card. I am trying to use Storage Access Framework to get thoose perissions.

But when i start the Activity using the following code.

`startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE), 42);`

i am getting the following empty Recent list with no other option to select Internal Memory or SD Card in my Phone (Android Version 5.1.)

[Phone Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kopln.png)

Whereas the Emulator running Android 5.1 shows SD card memory.

[Emulator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2PvU.png)

Could anyone please suggest what is wrong? Because couple of other applications(ES Explorer,MP3 Editer) asked for permission in my phone where i was able to select the SD Card.

Comment: Look in menu and enable option to show sd card and so.

Comment: There is no Menu Option at all. As you can see the Screenshot. I tried with  menu key too. no use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it by adding an extra to the Document Tree intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE");
intent.putExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: Didnt work for me, i can only use if i create a new folder